# Interacting SWIG modules with and without `-builtin`

Tags: python, c++, swig

How can I tell a module compiled *without* `-builtin` that an `%import`ed module is compiled *with* `-builtin`?  Doing this naively gives me segfaults when the non-builtin module assumes that objects from the first module have wrappers.

(I never get segfaults if everything is compiled with `-builtin` turned *off*, or when using the second module alone with `-builtin` turned on; it's just when using them together with different compilation options.)

## Details

I have several separate modules that I use SWIG for.  Let's say one of them is named `A`, and contains fundamental objects (quaternions).  Because it contains basic objects that are involved in many computations, I prefer to use SWIG's `-builtin` option for it.  I have tested it, and this does make a pretty significant difference in timing.

Now, I also have another module named `B` which needs to use objects from `A`.  But `B` contains big fat composite objects that I don't act on very many times, so I don't expect that there's much advantage in using `-builtin` here.  Moreover, I really like to extend the classes in `B`, and do various things that are not possible with `-builtin`.

The problem is that I have to `%import A.i` inside of `B.i`.  But then the code that's generated for `B` assumes that `A` objects have the extra wrappers, rather than using `-builtin`.  So when I use `B`, I get segfaults.

(At least, I assume the segfaults result because `B` assumes the extra wrappers.  I looked through my `B_wrap.cpp` file enough to see that it was assuming the presence of those wrappers, though I can't really say that I did any test to ensure that's where the problem was coming from.  But the segfaults did coincide only with uses of `A` from `B`.  On its own, `A` has never given me any trouble.  Also, if I compile `A` and `B` without `-builtin`, I never get segfaults.)

In principle, I could use [MONK's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475071/1194883) and just subclass any class that I need to add methods to, while compiling everything with `-builtin`.  But this would break the nice correspondence between names in my C++ code and names in my python code, as well as requiring one or other set of users to change the names they use, as well as being a general pain in the butt.

I apologize for not having a MWE, but I think it would be an unreasonably large MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that it's possible to compile with separate flags, but I have satisfied myself with MONK's solution.  In combination with SWIG's `%rename` functionality, MONK's approach doesn't require renaming anything visible to the user.  Plus, it's easy to implement, requiring just five extra lines per class I want to modify.  Thus, everything gets to be compiled with `-builtin`, and no segfaults.  Though this doesn't technically answer the question I asked at the top, it suits me.

So, let's suppose that the crucial object inside `B` is a class named `Classy`.  I'll just tell SWIG to rename this to `_Classy` (the underscore so that I don't have to look at it every time I use tab completion in ipython).  Then, I'll make an empty metaclass that subclasses those objects.  Finally, I'll make a new object named `Classy` that just has the metaclass.  So my python users and my C++ users will see it as the same object, but python users will be able to subclass it.

Here's a MWE for this part of it.  A simple header:

```
// Classy.hpp
class Classy {
public:
  Classy() { }
};
```

And the SWIG file

```
// test.i
%module "test"

%{
  #include "Classy.hpp"
%}

%rename(_Classy) Classy;

%include "Classy.hpp"

%insert("python") %{
class _MetaClassy(type(_Classy)):
    pass
class Classy(_Classy):
    __metaclass__ = _MetaClassy
Classy.myattr = 'anything'
%}
```

(See how we added an attribute there at the end.)  And, finally, the setup file:

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
example_module = Extension('_test',
                           sources=['test_wrap.cxx'])
setup (name = 'test',
       ext_modules = [example_module],
       py_modules = ["test"])
```

Now, just compile and test with

```
swig -python -builtin -c++ test.i
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python -c 'import test; x=test.Classy(); print x.myattr'
```

In that last line, the python object `x`, which is of type `Classy`, does indeed have an attribute -- even though the C++ class had nothing at all.  So we've succeeded.

Presumably, this subclassing defeats the speed advantage of `-builtin` for the `Classy` object, but I had already decided that I don't care about that one class.  On the other hand, I get to retain the speed advantage for any objects that I don't explicitly subclass, so there is still a reason to use `builtin`.